# How to automatically generate a matrix by given values in 1-d-matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix

I've tried using a for-loop to generate each column in an list-array, which worked. But unfortunantly I cant use this list in the np.append(matrix_name, values(=list), axis=0) comand to add those values as a column to a defined matrix X with the size of 10x10.

Approximately it should look like this: https://abload.de/image.php?img=xxxl4k8a.png

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
np.tile(np.arange(1, 11), (10, 1)).cumprod(axis=0)
```

Let's see what we're doing in detail.

Generate first row

```
np.arange(1, 11)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Repeat it ten times

```
np.tile(np.arange(1, 11), (10, 1))
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Multiply each row by the previous one along axis 0

```
np.tile(np.arange(1, 11), (10, 1)).cumprod(axis=0)
array([[          1,           2,           3,           4,           5,
                  6,           7,           8,           9,          10],
       [          1,           4,           9,          16,          25,
                 36,          49,          64,          81,         100],
       [          1,           8,          27,          64,         125,
                216,         343,         512,         729,        1000],
       [          1,          16,          81,         256,         625,
               1296,        2401,        4096,        6561,       10000],
       [          1,          32,         243,        1024,        3125,
               7776,       16807,       32768,       59049,      100000],
       [          1,          64,         729,        4096,       15625,
              46656,      117649,      262144,      531441,     1000000],
       [          1,         128,        2187,       16384,       78125,
             279936,      823543,     2097152,     4782969,    10000000],
       [          1,         256,        6561,       65536,      390625,
            1679616,     5764801,    16777216,    43046721,   100000000],
       [          1,         512,       19683,      262144,     1953125,
           10077696,    40353607,   134217728,   387420489,  1000000000],
       [          1,        1024,       59049,     1048576,     9765625,
           60466176,   282475249,  1073741824,  3486784401, 10000000000]])
```

Comment: This results in integer overflow in my system

Comment: @Brenlla python inherits default C type sizes, so default int is C long which is 64bit int almost on every 64bit system except Win64 which you're probably using. You should be able to avoid the overflow setting `dtype=np.uint64` in the first `np.arange`. Nothing to do with this question though, when you work with integers that big you should be careful about your platform limits.